# populating angular directive based on data and tag attribute

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm building an angular directive which will be in multiple places on the same page. I've got a few different video tags, and want to build something flexible enough that I can place the right video in the right location.

So, in my videoController, I've got an object which holds the video details

```
$scope.videos = {
     "main":{ webRTCStream: streamDetails},
     "guest":{ webRTCStream: streamDetails},
     "other": { webRTCStream: streamDetails}
}
```

then I have a stream directive

```
.directive('stream', function(){
       return {
             restrict: 'E',
             controller: 'videoController',
             template: '<video></video>',
             link: function(){
                elm[0].firstChild.src=URL.createObjectURL(stream);
                elm[0].firstChild.play();
             }
       }
});
```

I'd like my html to be

```
<stream data-name="main"></stream>
<stream data-name="guest"></stream>
<stream data-name="other"></stream>
```

What is the best way to select the correct stream to put into the correct directive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind your video information with a two way databinding in your directive:

```
app.directive('stream', function(){
       return {
             restrict: 'E',
             template: '<video></video>',
             scope:{
               name: '='
             },
             link: function(scope, element, attr){
               var video = element.find('video');
               video.attr('src', scope.name);
               video[0].play();
             }
       }
});
```

And bind the video information like this:

```
<stream data-name="videos.main"></stream>
<stream data-name="videos.guest"></stream>
<stream data-name="videos.other"></stream>
```

See this [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/UhFJWqiN4ZgX8rpjxnlC?p=preview) for a simplified solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this to get data-name from your view...

```
.directive('stream', function(){
       return {
             restrict: 'E',
             controller: 'videoController',
             scope: { data-name: '='},
             template: '<video></video>',
             link: function(){
                elm[0].firstChild.src=URL.createObjectURL(stream);
                elm[0].firstChild.play();
             }
       } 
});
```

Then you can use data-name in your controller to get the right object from the video array and boom.